# Why do colleges force students to study for so many years when most of won't be needed?

Tags: job, academic-life, industry

I have all the respect for students of sciences who go to a university to fully divulge themselves into a certain topic and understand it in and out.

But the truth is, that description simply doesn't fit most students. Most students go to university because they want a degree so they can get a job, and a lot of the stuff you'll learn simply isn't useful.

The obvious example is computer-science (but it applies to many other fields too, like engineering, economics, etc). If you study computer science at a university, and then choose to enter the field of software engineering, 95 % of your degree will be useless. In software engineering, it's mostly just knowing your tech and being able to code efficiently in it.

So why are students being forced to spend years and years studying to obtain a degree to get a job when that degree simply isn't necessary for that job?

Obviously you don't NEED to get a degree, but in today's environment, most employers expect it, so your hands are forced.

This seems like a gigantic waste for all of society.

Comment: I do suspect that in many cases education could be made radically more efficient, but here are a couple points: 1) It's only recently that programming as a career has existed, and only in the past ten years or so has it become easy to teach yourself to program online, so the system hasn't had much time to adapt yet; 2) I think a major idea behind university education is that it's good for society if people know about things like history and philosophy and literature so that we can have a more enlightened civilization and be more informed voters.

Comment: "95% of your degree will be useless."  Probably so.  The thing is, you don't know in advance *which* 95% will be useless...

Comment: @NateEldredge Agree. Also, large part of university training to acquire skills, learn methods and approaches of the field, gain a perspective so latter one can pick new information faster. It is not just about memorizing the 5 most important piece of lexical information from some laundry list.Even learning languages is more than just remembering the 100 most common words of a language. STEM is more then remembering 10 - 20 math tricks.

Comment: If you aren't using 95% of whats taught of in a CS program in a job in software engineering, you might not be doing software engineering at all.

Comment: "If you study computer science at a university, and then choose to enter the field of software engineering," But what if you don't?

Comment: Please edit out the ranty parts and I'd be happy to retract my close vote.

Comment: Teaching people how to *think* is under appreciated. Likewise, learning things like history and psychology lays a contextual foundation that helps structure thought in a variety of situations. I wouldn’t want to live in a world full of totally specialized individuals.

Comment: I think a lot of the commenters here are missing the point in the original question which is not "is a University degree valuable?" but rather "why should seemingly every job *require* one when a) many jobs that do require such can be done without if one has the right skills obtained otherwise and b) [perhaps not mentioned but others who argue along these lines have brought it up] University education is so expensive, sometimes even creating a lifetime of unpayable debt?"

Comment: Lad, CS is a lot more than knowing a language.  What is your basis that engineers don't use but a fraction of their education.  This is baseless.  The are masters and PhDs.  If you learned more than needed as an undergrad there would be no purposed to an advanced degree.

Answer (score 6):

> Because nobody has a crystal ball to see the future.

By having a reasonably broad curriculum, a university can prepare the students for a good deal of possible scenarios, which gives them flexibility.  No more jobs in your specific subfield? With the adequate background, provided by a good university, you can pivot fields to keep earning your pay. Been there, done that, it's quite handy :)

Answer (score 5):

University education is about education, not training. The university wants to contribute to an educated citizenry, not just industrial drones. You can, as you know, turn yourself into a drone, but don't try to make university education so impoverished, please. I studied mathematics. My daughter studied philosophy. Neither of those is training for anything specific. But we both learned how to think and to evaluate and to learn.

But even in CS you are very wrong about what is useful and what is useless. The most important skill isn't your use of existing technology to do something that someone wants done. The most important skill is to understand what *should be built*. Only then can you participate in the future without damaging the world and civilization.

There was a news article in the past couple of days that discusses the fact that at some large and important companies, Google in this case, are asking *why are we building this*. It is a very important question that you will get answered if you study history, philosophy, ethics, psychology, literature, etc. You won't get a sufficient answer by studying Java and DotNet and SQL.

European education is a bit different and the necessary education in what makes us human is normally taught to students before they enter the university. In the US, it is a continuous process, but secondary education often falls short, so, traditionally in the US it has been an important aspect of an undergraduate education. Graduate education is for specialization, but even there, it isn't just the technology to build todays tchotchkes.

What seems useless to you is what makes the future of the planet and its people viable.

Comment: "There was a news article in the past couple of days that discusses the fact that at some large and important companies, Google in this case, are asking why are we building this. It is a very important question that you will get answered if you study history, philosophy, ethics, psychology, literature, etc. " 

However, to really answer that you need people *specialized* in those fields, no? So if you specialize in something *not* those specifically, how does that help in that regard?

Comment: Moreover, this seems to put serious kosh on that nonsense that goes around on conservative internet sites about that there are such things as "useless" college majors (typically named are "liberal arts"-type majors.). A college major is more as useful or useless as *you* make it to be and what *you* get out of it, in the end.

Comment: If your educational system includes a viable vocational training sector (like Germany and the Netherlands), then students have a choice, between getting trained at "only useful stuff" and being educated. In these countries, people with vocational training typically earn a good living and are able to attain a stable career. However, people who have learned all the "useless stuff" at a university tend to do even better (higher income, lower unemployment, etc.)  There are exceptions, but the overall pattern is clear. Apparently, employers want to pay for useless stuff...

Answer (score 4):

The universities don't have much of a choice in this matter. Whenever the university issues a degree in [topic], it's staking its name and reputation that the recipient of the degree is competent in [topic]. If the degree holder turns out to be unable to answer basic questions on [topic], then the university's degree is worthless and its reputation in tatters. For example, I would genuinely wonder what a university is doing if its physics graduates don't understand classical electromagnetism.

In other words, the real crux of your question is:

> Obviously you don't NEED to get a degree, but in today's environment, most employers expect it, so your hands are forced.

If most of the things that are taught in degrees aren't needed, why are most employers expecting a degree? That is a question for another Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

I must admit that your question reads like a bit of a rant but the basic question still deserves an answer.

You are right that most of the "factual content" of the college education is not used by most employees after their university education. However, **"learning facts" should not be the primary goal of a college education**.

Ultimately, the goal of higher education is (or at least I strongly believe should be) to teach students three main abilities: critical thinking, independent learning, and communication. These are tools that are universally applicable and allow graduates to be adaptable to an ever-changing environment. The issue is that you can't teach those abilities in the abstract—you need to have *something* to build that around and that's where the formal content of the college curriculum comes into play.